# What are these ugly spots in smoke simulation render and how can I fix them?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Here are some images attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If your _Render Properties_ are still the same like in the file you uploaded in your other question, I would suspect the _Transparent_ bounces are too low at a value of 8. Go to _Render Properties_ > _Light Paths_ > _Max Bounces_ and set _Transparent_ (not _Transmission_!) to something like 64. Maybe you could set _Volume_ to 1 as well, but this will increase your render time. If that does not help, the file I have here is also set to directly render as video and the _Quality_ is set to _Medium Quality_... this could well be compression artifacts in the video file.

Comment: I would anyway always suggest to render out an image sequence first if you are not doing a quick simple rneder to see the overall animation. If anything goes wrong you can always continue rendering from where it stopped while a video file needs to be rendered from start to finish each time. And you can save the images in a high quality and then make a video from them in either Blender's _Video Sequence Editor_ or even better any other video editing software like DaVinci Resolve to optimize the quality settings etc. of the video.